# Error logging in with Google :"An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request."

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[image]

My code enters Googlelogin, but it explodes before entering ExternalResponse

Note: This is my first question here, sorry if I missed anything.

```
public IActionResult GoogleLogin(string returnUrl)
{
    returnUrl = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl);
    string redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalResponse", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action("ExternalResponse") };
    return Challenge(properties, "Google");
}

//CreateBy Burak

public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalResponse(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
    if (authenticateResult?.Succeeded != true)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, authenticateResult.Principal);

    var user = authenticateResult.Principal;
    var userName = user.Identity.Name;
    var userEmail = user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
    var userDisplayName = user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
 
    var contactPersonAccount = new ContactPersonAccount
    {
        UserName = userName,
        NameSurname = userDisplayName,
        //Email = userEmail,

    };


    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}

public IActionResult GoogleLogin(string returnUrl)
{
    returnUrl = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl);
    string redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalResponse", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action("ExternalResponse") };
    return Challenge(properties, "Google");
}

//CreateBy Burak

public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalResponse(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
    var authenticateResult = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
    if (authenticateResult?.Succeeded != true)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, authenticateResult.Principal);

    var user = authenticateResult.Principal;
    var userName = user.Identity.Name;
    var userEmail = user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
    var userDisplayName = user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
 
    var contactPersonAccount = new ContactPersonAccount
    {
        UserName = userName,
        NameSurname = userDisplayName,
        //Email = userEmail,

    };


    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: Either your *ReturnUrl* is not set in Google Console for the respective Google app or you have set it different than *ExternalResponse*. I cannot see the full URL in the image you shared. Can you please share the full URL?

Comment: @VikramSinghSain   RedirectUri="/AdminPanel/Home/ExternalResponse" Authorized redirect URIs = http://localhost:57178/signin-google      It gives an error without entering ExterRespons

Comment: You mentioned Authorized redirect URI as `localhost:57178/signin-google`. I hope you set it in Google Console. If yes, then set *Redirect URI* as `https://localhost:57178/AdminPanel/Home/ExternalResponse` in Google console.